# the py file pyinstaller,subprocess.run can't run

Tags: python

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
import subprocess
def create_and_write_txt(*args):
    cmd = '"C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2022/bin/mayabatch.exe" -file "E:/Maya_Project/scenes/input/null_scene.mb" -script "E:/Maya_Project/scenes/output/LuanchMelScript.mel" "-noAutoloadPlugins"'
    subprocess.run(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

class App(QWidget):

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 Button Example")
    self.resize(300, 200)
    self.button = QPushButton("Execute", self)
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
@pyqtSlot()
def on_click(self):
    create_and_write_txt()
app = QApplication([])
ex = App()
ex.show()
app.exec_()
```

This Python code works fine in pycharm, but when packaged, subprocess.run is not executed

I use this pyinstaller to bundle the module:
pyinstaller -D E:\Python3.10_Project\Batch_Tool.py -i E:\Python3.10_Project\image\Batch_Tool.ico

I try pyinstaller Batch_Tool.py,and run Batch_Tool.exe,The following error has occurred:
returned non-zero exit status 3221226505
[image]

Comment: Could you capture its output with `capture_output=True` and print it?

Comment: As far as I understand, you are using pyinstaller to bundle the module that contains  **class App** as a standalone tool? Could you please provide some informations about how you build it? What is the pyinstaller command you are using? Also is there an error displayed when running the packaged script?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that there should be two indented lines after the def create_and_write_txt(*args): line.

Could it be the extra quotes that you have around -noAutoloadPlugins in the cmd?

Comment: This is not the cause of the indented lines.
This code can run in IDE pycharm,After I pyinstaller,is not execute
subprocess,may be my parameter set error.
anyway,thank you